# nestjs elasticSearch stream/web module error

Tags: elasticsearch, nestjs

```js
node_modules/undici/types/fetch.d.ts:7:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream/web' or its corresponding type declarations.

7 import { ReadableStream } from 'stream/web'
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error(s).

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

If I call `elasticSearchService` in nestjs, the above error occurs.

I searched for the error, but couldn't find a solution. How can I solve this?

`npm i --save @nestjs/elasticsearch @elastic/elasticsearch` This command did not run, so I installed it as `yarn add @nestjs/elasticsearch @elastic/elasticsearch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue also, It looks like in version 8.0.0 of elasticsearch client they migrate to the "undici" http client
release notes can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/changelog-client.html#_migrate_to_the_undici_http_client)

This may be used in the agent [option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/basic-config.html)

As for workaround solution I've downgrade my elasticsearch version to the latest version without undici which is `7.17.0`

Answer (score 3):

i solved with
`yarn add '@types/node'` command

Comment: I had the same error using `vercel dev` (  `Cannot find module 'stream/web' or its corresponding type declarations.`

`7 import { ReadableStream } from 'stream/web'` )

And your answer worked for me ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First check the node version `node -v`. if version is below 16, then you should use updated node version. Below steps might be helpful to switch node version.

- To list out the node version use `nvm list`.
- To install certain node version use `nvm install v18.13.0`.
- Finally, use nvm to update the node version `nvm use v18.13.0`.